# Ubuntu Realtek R8168

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

Dropped driver from R8169 to R8168 and internet speed is fine.  However, downloads are deadly slow and fail either instantly or at some point during the download.  IPv6 has been disabled to test if that was the culprit or not, but alas to no avail.  This applies to Ethernet only since I'm using Intel Wireless.

If logs would be helpful feel free to ask and I can provide.

Cheers,

Jako81624